# Oracle - select inside select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that works on MSSQL, but when I run it on Oracle DB it fails:

```
SELECT ( CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM DA_TRANSACTION) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS isEmpty
```

The error that I get:

Error in SQL Query: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

How to modify my query so it will work in Oracle as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle needs a `FROM` clause.  And it provides a one-row table for this purpose:

```
SELECT ( CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM DA_TRANSACTION) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS isEmpty
FROM DUAL;
```

If you want an efficient version that works in either database (and you are using Oracle 12C+):

```
select count(*) as isEmpty
from (select 1
      from da_transaction
      offset 0 fetch first 1 row only
     ) t
```